I lost "Run" tab from bottom line toolbox it randomly appeared in "Debug" how to fix it
Run tab unavailable
settings in service
I'm using the Spring framework while running the application and encountered the arrangement of tabs. The project is working fine but suddenly "Run -> console" I lost this tab. So I debugged the application I found the "Run" tab is available under "Debug" Ideally it should be separate from everything.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

you can just hold the "run" tab and drag it to the desired location, or you can go to window then restore default layout to return it as defaults.
hope this helps

Yes. Thanks (windows layout) it works for me.
